# how to detect more than one error in yacc

Tags: yacc

in this code (parser for c language using yacc ) after detecting the first error the program execution stops. what do i do so that all the errors are shown and then only the program executions stops. I read some where you can use yyerrork but i couldnt apply it. Please help.

```
    %token IDENTIFIER CONSTANT STRING_LITERAL SIZEOF
%token PTR_OP INC_OP DEC_OP LEFT_OP RIGHT_OP LE_OP GE_OP EQ_OP NE_OP
%token AND_OP OR_OP MUL_ASSIGN DIV_ASSIGN MOD_ASSIGN ADD_ASSIGN
%token SUB_ASSIGN LEFT_ASSIGN RIGHT_ASSIGN AND_ASSIGN
%token XOR_ASSIGN OR_ASSIGN TYPE_NAME
```

%token TYPEDEF EXTERN STATIC AUTO REGISTER
%token CHAR SHORT INT LONG SIGNED UNSIGNED FLOAT DOUBLE CONST VOLATILE VOID
%token STRUCT UNION ENUM ELLIPSIS

%token CASE DEFAULT IF ELSE SWITCH WHILE DO FOR GOTO CONTINUE BREAK RETURN

%start translation_unit
%%

primary_expression
    : IDENTIFIER
    | CONSTANT
    | STRING_LITERAL
    | '(' expression ')'
    ;

postfix_expression
    : primary_expression
    | postfix_expression '[' expression ']'
    | postfix_expression '(' ')'
    | postfix_expression '(' argument_expression_list ')'
    | postfix_expression '.' IDENTIFIER
    | postfix_expression PTR_OP IDENTIFIER
    | postfix_expression INC_OP
    | postfix_expression DEC_OP
    ;

argument_expression_list
    : assignment_expression
    | argument_expression_list ',' assignment_expression
    ;

unary_expression
    : postfix_expression
    | INC_OP unary_expression
    | DEC_OP unary_expression
    | unary_operator cast_expression
    | SIZEOF unary_expression
    | SIZEOF '(' type_name ')'
    ;

unary_operator
    : '&'
    | '*'
    | '+'
    | '-'
    | '~'
    | '!'
    ;

cast_expression
    : unary_expression
    | '(' type_name ')' cast_expression
    ;

multiplicative_expression
    : cast_expression
    | multiplicative_expression '*' cast_expression
    | multiplicative_expression '/' cast_expression
    | multiplicative_expression '%' cast_expression
    ;

additive_expression
    : multiplicative_expression
    | additive_expression '+' multiplicative_expression
    | additive_expression '-' multiplicative_expression
    ;

shift_expression
    : additive_expression
    | shift_expression LEFT_OP additive_expression
    | shift_expression RIGHT_OP additive_expression
    ;

relational_expression
    : shift_expression
    | relational_expression '<' shift_expression
    | relational_expression '>' shift_expression
    | relational_expression LE_OP shift_expression
    | relational_expression GE_OP shift_expression
    ;

equality_expression
    : relational_expression
    | equality_expression EQ_OP relational_expression
    | equality_expression NE_OP relational_expression
    ;

and_expression
    : equality_expression
    | and_expression '&' equality_expression
    ;

exclusive_or_expression
    : and_expression
    | exclusive_or_expression '^' and_expression
    ;

inclusive_or_expression
    : exclusive_or_expression
    | inclusive_or_expression '|' exclusive_or_expression
    ;

logical_and_expression
    : inclusive_or_expression
    | logical_and_expression AND_OP inclusive_or_expression
    ;

logical_or_expression
    : logical_and_expression
    | logical_or_expression OR_OP logical_and_expression
    ;

conditional_expression
    : logical_or_expression
    | logical_or_expression '?' expression ':' conditional_expression
    ;

assignment_expression
    : conditional_expression
    | unary_expression assignment_operator assignment_expression
    ;

assignment_operator
    : '='
    | MUL_ASSIGN
    | DIV_ASSIGN
    | MOD_ASSIGN
    | ADD_ASSIGN
    | SUB_ASSIGN
    | LEFT_ASSIGN
    | RIGHT_ASSIGN
    | AND_ASSIGN
    | XOR_ASSIGN
    | OR_ASSIGN
    ;

expression
    : assignment_expression
    | expression ',' assignment_expression
    ;

constant_expression
    : conditional_expression
    ;

declaration
    : declaration_specifiers ';'
    | declaration_specifiers init_declarator_list ';'
    ;

declaration_specifiers
    : storage_class_specifier
    | storage_class_specifier declaration_specifiers
    | type_specifier
    | type_specifier declaration_specifiers
    | type_qualifier
    | type_qualifier declaration_specifiers
    ;

init_declarator_list
    : init_declarator
    | init_declarator_list ',' init_declarator
    ;

init_declarator
    : declarator
    | declarator '=' initializer
    ;

storage_class_specifier
    : TYPEDEF
    | EXTERN
    | STATIC
    | AUTO
    | REGISTER
    ;

type_specifier
    : VOID
    | CHAR
    | SHORT
    | INT
    | LONG
    | FLOAT
    | DOUBLE
    | SIGNED
    | UNSIGNED
    | struct_or_union_specifier
    | enum_specifier
    | TYPE_NAME
    ;

struct_or_union_specifier
    : struct_or_union IDENTIFIER '{' struct_declaration_list '}'
    | struct_or_union '{' struct_declaration_list '}'
    | struct_or_union IDENTIFIER
    ;

struct_or_union
    : STRUCT
    | UNION
    ;

struct_declaration_list
    : struct_declaration
    | struct_declaration_list struct_declaration
    ;

struct_declaration
    : specifier_qualifier_list struct_declarator_list ';'
    ;

specifier_qualifier_list
    : type_specifier specifier_qualifier_list
    | type_specifier
    | type_qualifier specifier_qualifier_list
    | type_qualifier
    ;

struct_declarator_list
    : struct_declarator
    | struct_declarator_list ',' struct_declarator
    ;

struct_declarator
    : declarator
    | ':' constant_expression
    | declarator ':' constant_expression
    ;

enum_specifier
    : ENUM '{' enumerator_list '}'
    | ENUM IDENTIFIER '{' enumerator_list '}'
    | ENUM IDENTIFIER
    ;

enumerator_list
    : enumerator
    | enumerator_list ',' enumerator
    ;

enumerator
    : IDENTIFIER
    | IDENTIFIER '=' constant_expression
    ;

type_qualifier
    : CONST
    | VOLATILE
    ;

declarator
    : pointer direct_declarator
    | direct_declarator
    ;

direct_declarator
    : IDENTIFIER
    | '(' declarator ')'
    | direct_declarator '[' constant_expression ']'
    | direct_declarator '[' ']'
    | direct_declarator '(' parameter_type_list ')'
    | direct_declarator '(' identifier_list ')'
    | direct_declarator '(' ')'
    ;

pointer
    : '*'
    | '*' type_qualifier_list
    | '*' pointer
    | '*' type_qualifier_list pointer
    ;

type_qualifier_list
    : type_qualifier
    | type_qualifier_list type_qualifier
    ;

parameter_type_list
    : parameter_list
    | parameter_list ',' ELLIPSIS
    ;

parameter_list
    : parameter_declaration
    | parameter_list ',' parameter_declaration
    ;

parameter_declaration
    : declaration_specifiers declarator
    | declaration_specifiers abstract_declarator
    | declaration_specifiers
    ;

identifier_list
    : IDENTIFIER
    | identifier_list ',' IDENTIFIER
    ;

type_name
    : specifier_qualifier_list
    | specifier_qualifier_list abstract_declarator
    ;

abstract_declarator
    : pointer
    | direct_abstract_declarator
    | pointer direct_abstract_declarator
    ;

direct_abstract_declarator
    : '(' abstract_declarator ')'
    | '[' ']'
    | '[' constant_expression ']'
    | direct_abstract_declarator '[' ']'
    | direct_abstract_declarator '[' constant_expression ']'
    | '(' ')'
    | '(' parameter_type_list ')'
    | direct_abstract_declarator '(' ')'
    | direct_abstract_declarator '(' parameter_type_list ')'
    ;

initializer
    : assignment_expression
    | '{' initializer_list '}'
    | '{' initializer_list ',' '}'
    ;

initializer_list
    : initializer
    | initializer_list ',' initializer
    ;

statement
    : labeled_statement
    | compound_statement
    | expression_statement
    | selection_statement
    | iteration_statement
    | jump_statement
    ;

labeled_statement
    : IDENTIFIER ':' statement
    | CASE constant_expression ':' statement
    | DEFAULT ':' statement
    ;

compound_statement
    : '{' '}'
    | '{' statement_list '}'
    | '{' declaration_list '}'
    | '{' declaration_list statement_list '}'
    ;

declaration_list
    : declaration
    | declaration_list declaration
    ;

statement_list
    : statement
    | statement_list statement
    ;

expression_statement
    : ';'
    | expression ';'
    ;

selection_statement
    : IF '(' expression ')' statement
    | IF '(' expression ')' statement ELSE statement
    | SWITCH '(' expression ')' statement
    ;

iteration_statement
    : WHILE '(' expression ')' statement
    | DO statement WHILE '(' expression ')' ';'
    | FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement ')' statement
    | FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement expression ')' statement
    ;

jump_statement
    : GOTO IDENTIFIER ';'
    | CONTINUE ';'
    | BREAK ';'
    | RETURN ';'
    | RETURN expression ';'
    ;

translation_unit
    : external_declaration
    | translation_unit external_declaration
    ;

external_declaration
    : function_definition
    | declaration
    ;

function_definition
    : declaration_specifiers declarator declaration_list compound_statement
    | declaration_specifiers declarator compound_statement
    | declarator declaration_list compound_statement
    | declarator compound_statement
    ;

%%

## include

extern char yytext[];
extern int column;

yyerror(s)
char *s;
{
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("\n%*s\n%*s\n", column, "^", column, s);
}

Answer (score 2):

You need to give yacc some rules to recover from the syntax error and attempt to continue.  In your grammar, you might add a rule like:

```
declaration: error ';'
```

This rule will make it possible to recover from errors seen while parsing a declaration -- the parser will scan through the input until it sees a ';' and say that's the end of the declaration and attempt to continue from there.  You might also add rules like:

```
struct_or_union_specifier
    : struct_or_union IDENTIFIER '{' error '}'
    | struct_or_union '{' error '}'
```

to skip up to the next `}` when you hit an error in a struct specifier.  You can experiment with adding more rules, but it gets tricky to figure out which error recovery rule will get used in any given situation (yacc pops states until it finds one that has an action for an error, so you really need to understand the state machine it builds for your parser)

Comment: can you please tell the whole code please..i am not an expert in yacc i tried what you said but couldnt get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Boy this takes me back a few years. I thought folk use Bison now. It is tricky to recover from errors, YACC tries to re-right things. I remember sometimes having to play with the stack, and use yyerrok so the parser could continue. Remember that when things go south there is often a good reason, and that good reason ripples though creating many false positives. That said, with a lot of finagling, if you know your grammer, and if you are willing to tweak your grammer, some pretty good error recovery is possible.

I found a URL to the reference I used to use: http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/index.html